# How to disallow a directory in server with robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I have two domains in the same server and I want to disallow search engines in one of these:

`www.example.com` -> pointing to root
`www.example.net` -> pointing to directory

I added a robots.txt in a directory of `.net` for disallow all for `www.example.net` like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

I'm doing the right thing? Am I disallowing the search engines only in `.net`?

Comment: If your file is available at `www.domain.com/robots.txt` it will be read.

Comment: @hebron OP wanted to know if the `.com` redirection to `.net` would cause their `robots.txt` not to be read. See my answer..

Comment: That is not how I understand his question, my understanding is that the `.net` domain is pointing to a folder below the `.com` domain. And that he has added the `robots.txt` to that directory.

Comment: Yes, @hebron the robot.txt is added to that directory. Is not possible disallow only one directory or domain if there are in the same directory? Are you exactly sure? Thanks for patience.

Comment: If they are in the same directory then no, you should read about canonical URLs: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the info! It helped me to know more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen on [this page](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html), yes, you're doing exactly the right thing:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

If the two websites are located in the same directory, there is no way as far as I'm aware of disallowing robots.txt just for one site.
However, as the same page also states, this only works with `well behaved robots`, meaning that some search engines could dismiss the robots.txt entirely.

If you *really* need the `.net` to be secured from search-engines, the one foolproof way of doing this is by adding a username and password protection in .htaccess (any user accessing the `.net` will also have to have the username/password):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

.htpasswd:

```
[user]:[password]
```

Comment: Thanks for information! I understand that is not possible disallow only a directory or domain because are in the same directory.